# how do I export svn repository to git when I don't have svn credential?

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I have a full checkout of svn repository in a folder. But I don't have the credentials of the svn repository(hosted in Unfuddle). I want to move this folder to a new git repostitory ( Github) with all its history and changes intact . If possible I would like to keep the commiters .
How do I export my exiting svn folder to Github ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An SVN checkout does not include it's own history, so all you can do is treat it as a normal set of files.

```
git init newgit
svn export yourcheckout newgit
git commit -a newgit
```

svn export will copy all the files except the hidden .svn directories. git commit -a will recursively add everything to change control and commit it. You'll be prompted for a commit note, of course.

To publish it to github, first create an account at github, then go here to create a repository:

http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

Let's say you called it test and your account is prabesh, so it's full name is

```
git@github.com:prabesh/test.git
```

The full details of what to do are shown on github when you create a repo, but once your repo exists, you can upload your local svn exported git repo to github, by registering the remote (github) repo, and pushing your local copy to it:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:prabesh/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I was searching if I could retain the history of diffs and logs . But since I don't have the credentials, I think I can do nothing but to create a new repo.

Comment: Surely you can contact Unfuddle to recover the credentials? If you can do that, then you can use `git-svn` - an add-on to git that will allow you to import your SVN repo including it's history. You would be able to execute `git svn clone svnrepo`.

Comment: it might seems a little weird but the previous developer has left and all remain with me is a folder full of code. Just trying to figure our why he wrote what he wrote ;)